# Add pdf table in PDF Document

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am generating a simple pdf file with a table in it.When I add some phrase in the document it works fine but also I am Adding a table inside this document but the table is not getting added in the document.Can anyone tell me what mistake I am doing here ? Thanks in Advance.
Here is my Code for generating pdf.Everything is fine except pdf table

```
public Document GetPDFparams(Document disclaimer)
    {
        StringBuilder Content = new StringBuilder();
        Content.Append("Testing");
        Paragraph NullContent = new Paragraph(Content.ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, font_size, Font.NORMAL));
        disclaimer.Add(NullContent);
        PdfPTable tableh = new PdfPTable(6);
        tableh.WidthPercentage = 100;
        tableh.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { 300f, 300f, 300f, 300f,300f,300f });
        tableh.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

        iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/ORIXLOGO.png"));
        //img.ScaleToFit(100, 40);
        PdfPCell LogoCell = new PdfPCell(img);
        LogoCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
        LogoCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
        LogoCell.Colspan = 2;
        LogoCell.Padding = 20;
        LogoCell.Border = 0;
        LogoCell.Indent = 0;        

        tableh.AddCell(LogoCell);


        Phrase LogoText = new Phrase("abc", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, font_size));
        PdfPCell LogoTextCell = new PdfPCell(LogoText);
        LogoTextCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        LogoTextCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        LogoTextCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        LogoTextCell.PaddingTop = 15;
        LogoTextCell.PaddingBottom = 5;
        LogoTextCell.PaddingLeft = 5;
        LogoTextCell.PaddingRight = 5;
        tableh.AddCell(LogoTextCell);

        disclaimer.Add(tableh);
        return disclaimer;
    }
```

Comment: http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/how-to-create-table-in-pdf-document-using-Asp-Net-with-C-Sharp-and-itextsharp-1027.aspx

Comment: I am done with it but still table is not getting added in the document.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18040/Tutorials-on-creating-PDF-files-using-C

http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables

Comment: Thanks but I got the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.The problem was tha table has 6 columns per row and I was testing after adding only 3 columns, so After adding all 6 columns for a row table get added :).
Here is my Code :

```
 public Document GetPDFparams(Document disclaimer)
    {
        StringBuilder Content = new StringBuilder();
        Content.Append("Testing");
        Paragraph NullContent = new Paragraph(Content.ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, font_size, Font.NORMAL));
        disclaimer.Add(NullContent);
        PdfPTable tableh = new PdfPTable(6);
        tableh.WidthPercentage = 100;
        tableh.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { 30f, 30f, 30f, 30f,30f,30f });
        iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/ORIXLOGO.png"));
        //img.ScaleToFit(100, 40);
        PdfPCell LogoCell = new PdfPCell(img);
        LogoCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
        LogoCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
        LogoCell.Colspan = 2;
        LogoCell.Padding = 20;
        LogoCell.Border = 0;
        //LogoCell.Indent = 0;        

        tableh.AddCell(LogoCell);


        Phrase LogoText = new Phrase("abc", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, font_size));
        PdfPCell LogoTextCell = new PdfPCell(LogoText);
        LogoTextCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        LogoTextCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        LogoTextCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        tableh.AddCell(LogoTextCell);
        tableh.AddCell(LogoTextCell);
        tableh.AddCell(LogoTextCell);
        tableh.AddCell(LogoTextCell);

        disclaimer.Add(tableh);
        return disclaimer;
    }
```